# Remove initial focus of textbox when app starts?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have a search textbox, a listview and a few buttons, when the app starts the textbox has the focus so it displays the keyboard, blocking half my screen.
How do I prevent that ?

I already tried putting the focus on a button (and set the button to focusable=true) but that didn't work. Only thing that worked was focusable on the textbox, but then obviously you don't get the keyboard anymore when clicked.

Comment: Emulator or phone?  It does that automatically on the emulator I've noticed, but not on your phone.

Comment: this behaviour may change from phone to phone cause the default value of the Window soft Input mode is stateUnspecified. So you end up in the anything can happen when you start your activity!!! As far as I know, it will find at startup the first focusable object. If it is a focusable object that can have input text it will open the soft keyboard, if not it only focus.

Answer (score 4):

You can set "focusable" and "focusable in touch mode" to true for an element before your EditText. Or the nice way would be to handle it with the activity attribute "[Window Soft Input Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)".

Comment: actually the emulator didn't do that (or I would have asked the question sooner), and canfocus doesn't exist (?), but the windowssoftinputmode=statehidden did the trick. Thanx.

Comment: Just checked it and it's focusable. Glad it solved your problem. As I said in a comment. The default behavior is undefined so you what happens in the emulator and on the phone might be different.

Comment: windowssoftinputmode=statehidden helps indeed

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution of this problem is

Set in your parent layout next attributes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

And now, when activity starts this layout getting default focus. So textfield will not foucsed.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick fix, you can make one of your wrapper view (such as your main layout) focusable with

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

with this when your activity starts instead of your edittexts or textviews your layout'll gain focus.